# Using BW style for minted code highlighting not pure BW

Tags: highlighting, minted

I'm trying to use the minted package with bw style for JavaScript code highlighting. Under the document I added

```
  \usemintedstyle{bw}
```

and use highlighting like this:

```
\begin{minted}[fontfamily=courier, fontsize=\footnotesize]{js}
   window.variable = value;
\end{minted}
```

However, the word **window** is still green!? The same happens, if I write new Array(), **Array** is also green! How can I change this?

edit: full example: I'm compiling it with pdflatex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
  \usemintedstyle{bw}
  \begin{minted}[fontfamily=courier, fontsize=\footnotesize]{js}
    window.variable = value;
  \end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Seems like it's depending on the JavaScript Lexer and not the bw.py-style. I tried configuring it and setting each element to black, but the word **window** is still green!
How can I avoid the green words?

SOLUTION:

Could figure it out by myself:
I had to change the file bw.py in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Pygments-1.6-py2.7.egg/pygments/styles` and add further color specifications, like

```
Name: "#000000",
Text: "#000000",
```

as described in
http://pygments.org/docs/tokens/
and in
http://pbelmans.wordpress.com/2011/03/06/how-to-change-pygments-styles-and-a-university-of-antwerp-style/

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! And thanks for giving an MWE!

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a bug in `minted` (which I currently maintain). The [development version](https://github.com/gpoore/minted) treats style definitions in a slightly different way from the last release, and it is working correctly.

My guess is that in the old treatment of styles, style definitions could overlap somewhat in limited circumstances.  Since the `bw` style is more minimalistic, it probably doesn't create all of the macros that some styles do.  However, those macros would be created by the `default` style, and this was causing problems.  In the development version, each style has its own completely isolated set of macros, so such conflicts aren't possible.